# getCookie function does not return correct values

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function to my website which will return a value from a cookie if it exists or false if it does not. The function does not return false or the cookie value. What it returns is equal to an empty string.

```
function getCookie($cookiename){
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[ crypto::encrypt($cookiename, 'info') ])){ return false; }
    return $_COOKIE[ crypto::encrypt($cookiename, 'info') ];
}
```

Now if I would create a cookie named `testcookie`, it would appear as `83Jdn3idsf93Jdnfh234ksadnu3234` when it is encrypted. The cookie is made with the encrypted name and an encrypted value.

```
// Now if I would call the function like this:
if(getCookie("testcookie") !== false){
    echo getCookie("testcookie");
}
```

While using the function the name will be encrypted to the encrypted name. I have checked and made sure the cookie exists. So don't worry and please don't comment "Does the cookie exist?"

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Crypto is my own class library for encryption and decryption. I just usally decrypt my cookies.. As I did explain above. (Basicly it's just like md5 with my own algorithm in it)

**EDIT**: What is the crypto library and what does it do?

It is just a way to encrypt things easily, how do i call it?

```
crypto::encrypt(string $string, string $method){
    return $encrypted;
}
echo crypto::encrypt("EncryptMe", "info");
// Will output: Tt9ztswTYo2mlQi0rOI1C2F1UFRfiJTfsOLcNvNfhJteRTg75Vlk+j19AYuPqLxT
```

Comment: What kind if thing is crypto? What does `crypto::encrypt($cookiename, 'info')` return if you just output it? How do you get the name of the cookie when you set it?

Comment: The reason I'm asking, is because I suspects you're using the cookie name as a key to encrypt the word 'info', instead of vice versa. Or maybe, you encrypt the cookie name wrong. But I can't be sure without more context.

Comment: Please have a look at my new edit

Comment: New edits is made to explain the crypto::encrypt function

Comment: If that is the actual code of `crypto::encrypt`, then I don't see how this will work.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `encrypt` it's impossible to say what is wrong, except for the general observation that you call methods multiple times instead of capturing the value and testing the stored value - and you seem to assume that calling the same method with the same argument always yields the same results, and this is not guaranteed. The only explanation I have for the behavior you describe is that `encrypt` had a side effect that causes the first get cookie to return some text but causing the servos get cookie to fail. Again, posting the full code is the only way to know for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what you are trying to do because you seem to be using a non-standard library (`crypto`) and didn't give us reference what it is.

Assuming you are using the so-called "[defuse/php-encryption](https://packagist.org/packages/defuse/php-encryption)" library, then the problem is likely that you are providing a string (`"info"`) as the key to `Crypto::encrypt()`, and that is not correct - `Crypto::encrypt()` takes a key in the form of `Defuse\Crypto\Key`, and your compiler should have warned you about it.

If you want to encrypt using a passphrase (that Defuse calls "password" incorrectly), you should call `Crypto::encryptWithPassword()`.

Also, please note that encryption is a highly CPU intensive operation, and its not a good idea to perform it needlessly. In your code you are calling `encrypt()` twice with the exact same argument. Its a better idea to call it once, stored the result in a variable and then use the variable in all other places.

Comment: the string `"info"` is just the encryption method i want to use